# How to create HashMap<String, String> through JNI then parse to java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, hashmap, java-native-interface

Hi I want to secure my web url and app secret keys through Ndk, I want to create `hashmap` in app and also store key values statically then parse to java, I follow **Stackoverflow** answer like [Create HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058360) also [JNI passing objects from C++ to Java](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1173823) some method deprecated from above link and didn't find any way to do this, I created `HashMap` but it giving me error

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobject
Java_com_company_project_home_ui_MainActivity_getUrlMap(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");
    if(mapClass == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    jsize map_len = 1;
    jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, init, map_len);
    jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    char *key = (char*)"URL_TEST_API"  ;
    char *val = (char*)"home.php";
    env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, key, val);
    return hashMap;
}
```

**Error**

```
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 00dd8f2f  /data/app/com.company.project-1/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.company.project.home.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)+714)
```

Comment: Users of your app can get these URLs easily via any sniffer or proxy on rooted devices

Comment: A `char*` is not a `jobject`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved My Problem the main Problem I found in my code is I missed to add **JNICALL** after **JNIEXPORT** line, and as Key and val are not valid so I changed to Java String through C as mentioned by @Michael in above answer, now code working fine after some modification also change ()

```
    #include <jni.h>
        extern "C"
        JNIEXPORT jobject
        JNICALL
        Java_com_company_project_somePackage_SplashScreen_getHashMap(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {
           jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");
           if(mapClass == NULL)
           {
               return NULL;
           }
           jsize map_len = 1;
           jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
           jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, init, map_len);
           jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
           jenv->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, env->NewStringUTF("URL_TEST_API"), env->NewStringUTF("home.php"));
return hashMap;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`key` and `val` are not valid arguments for `HashMap.put`. You need to create Java strings from your C strings, e.g. using [`NewStringUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF).